# Can a character ever use multiple tomes of the same type?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, bonus-type

The [*manual of bodily health*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#manual-of-bodily-health), [*tome of understanding*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#tome-of-understanding), [*tome of clear thought*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#tome-of-clear-thought) and similar items grant their readers inherent an bonus to their ability scores. From what I understand, these bonuses increase the reader's actual base statistics and do not have to be tracked separately. Therefore, once used, it is impossible to tell from a character's sheet whether or not the character's used such an item.

Keeping the above in mind, is it ever allowed for a character to use multiple  copies of such item simultaneously so as to benefit from all of them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The magic books that grant inherent bonuses still grant bonuses, and an inherent bonus works just like any other bonus except it applies "to an ability score [and] results from powerful magic, such as a *wish* spell. A character is limited to a total inherent bonus of +5 to any ability score" (*DMG* 21). Also, the [*wish*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#wish) spell has some additional rules that explain how multiple *wishes* in rapid succession can be used to gain larger inherent bonuses.

Thus, like most other bonuses, inherent bonuses *don't* typically stack. So, for example, reading a second [*manual of gainful exercise +1*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#manual-of-gainful-exercise)—even simultaneously—provides the reader with the *same* +1 inherent bonus as a lone *manual* does. Want a bigger inherent bonus? Buy, create, or find a *manual* or *tome* that grants a bigger bonus. (Or find a way to use in a row more [*wishes*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#wish).)

It's rare when *any* published stat block explains *how* a creature's ability scores are derived: the *Monster Manual* provides the creature's original ability scores before racial adjustments if those ability scores aren't all 10s and 11s (like if the NPC has levels in an NPC class), and NPCs that take levels in non-NPC classes get the elite array, but the game relies on the reader doing the math to derive a creature's original statistics if items have provided bonuses—if the reader needs to know the frost giant jarl's Charisma score absent its *cloak of charisma +2* (*Monster Manual* 122-3), the reader must do that math himself: that bonus is already included in his stat block for convenience… despite neither *Monster Manual* nor individual monster description *saying* that's the case nor including entries like *Cha 18 (includes the +2 enhancement bonus from the* cloak of charisma +2 *and a +1 ability score increase from increased Hit Dice)*. (I suspect this is because such notes, while useful for PCs, aren't that useful for a monster that'll only be on the board for 30 minutes or whatever *and* such notes occupy *a lot* of page space!)

However, the game does seem to make it clear that it's important for the reader to know when a creature's benefited from *manuals* and *tomes*: the pregenerated NPCs have listed among their possessions *tomes* and *manuals* marked as *used* in *Bastion of Broken Souls* (48), the level 20 high priest has among his possessions an already-read *tome of understanding* in the *Dungeon Master's Guide II* (166), and the elder orb Kularkuthan in *Lords of Madness* "has read a *tome of leadership and influence +5*; his +5 inherent bonus to Charisma is included in [his] statistics block" (43). These aren't the only examples—there are many more. A similar note should be made on the character sheet of any PC that likewise consumes a *tome* or *manual*.

Comment: Excellent argument! Time to start tracking these things, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple, but they don't stack. So if you use a +1 *tome* you can still use a +5 *tome*. In the end, this is the same as having only used the +5 since they don’t stack, so it’s kind of wasteful, but the +1 doesn’t “block” the +5 or anything.

Also, the *tomes* give inherent-typed bonuses, not base stat increases. This is the same sort of bonus that *wish* can grant.